# Understanding FreeCodeCamp Exact Change challenge solution(re: reduce method)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reduce

I'm at the Exact Change challenge. I need to create a function that:

1. accepts purchase price as the first arg(*price*), payment as the second art(*cash*), cash in drawer arg(*cid*)
2. *cid* is a 2D arr, listing avail currency
3. return "Insufficient Funds", if *cid* is less than the change due, and return "Closed" if *cid* is equal to the change due
4. otherwise, return change in coin and bills, sorted in highest to lowest order
5. checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]) should return [["QUARTER", 0.50]]

I found this solution below on the forum, like it a lot as it's clean, and shows creating an object array with reduce()- but it's a bit confusing to understand the second reduce() method in the function. Below is the code:

```js
const denom = [
{name: 'ONE HUNDRED', val: 100.00},
{name: 'TWENTY', val: 20.00},
{name: 'TEN', val: 10.00},
{name: 'FIVE', val: 5.00},
{name: 'ONE', val: 1.00},
{name: 'QUARTER', val: 0.25},
{name: 'DIME', val: 0.10},
{name: 'NICKEL', val: 0.05},
{name: 'PENNY', val: 0.01} 
] //a template object 

function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid){
 let change = cash - price

 const register = cid.reduce(function(acc, curr){
  acc.total += curr[1]
  acc[curr[0]] = curr[1]
  return acc
 }, {total: 0}) //creating register object with reduce()

 if(register.total === change){
  return 'Closed'
 } //handle exact change

 if(register.total < change){
  return 'Insufficient Funds'
 } //return insufficient change

 let change_arr = denom.reduce(function(acc, curr){
  let value = 0 //while there is still money of this type in the drawer
     //and while the denom is larger than the change remaining
  while(register[curr.name] > 0 && change >= curr.val){
   change -= curr.val
   register[curr.name] -= curr.val
   value += curr.val
   change = Math.round(change*100)/100
  }

  if(value > 0){
   acc.push([curr.name, value])
  }
  return acc;
 }, [])

 if(change_arr.length<1 || change >0){
  return 'Insufficient Funds'
 }

 return change_arr
}


checkCashRegister(19.50, 20.00, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.10], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90.00], ["FIVE", 55.00], ["TEN", 20.00], ["TWENTY", 60.00], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100.00]]);
```

My questions is, it doesn't look like this code ever worked on handling the data we receive through the *cid* argument. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something about using the template array(const denom) and/or converting the cid argument into an object and/or array.

Could anyone explain what's going on on the second reduce method(let change_arr = denom.reduce()) in the function?

EDIT: I thought it doesn't worked on the *cid* argument and also the register object

Comment: The first reduce converts `cid` into and object called `register`, that has a format like `{PENNY: 1.01, NICKEL: 2.05, ...}`. From then on `register` is used instead of cid. This solution works very similarly to my solution here https://pastebin.com/Ud6dfkUy , but I reused the variable named `cid` on line 15 and I used a for loop instead of reduce the second time around, which might be a bit easier to follow

Comment: @Paulpro Thanks so much! I understand we converted the cid array into the register object- forgot to mention it. I thought it didn't work directly with the data in the object as it says "denom.reduce()" not "register.reduce()". Could you explain? Thanks again and i'll def check out your solution!

Comment: @Paulpro just read through your code- it's more advanced! haha i'll need to spend more time to understand yours

Comment: Inside the reduce the while loop uses `register[curr.name] > 0` to check if there is any of the denomination `curr.name` left to use as change. While there is change of that denomination available, it "uses" it by subtracting  (`register[curr.name] -= curr.val`) inside the loop.